# What is the difference between RRMSE and RMSRE?

Tags: cross-validation, error, computational-statistics, validation

I've just found the following paragraph in a published article, where two dimensionless forms of RMSE are used, namely: relative root mean squared error (RRMSE) and root mean squared relative error. My question is: the is the difference between them? And, can we use the rules of thumb provided with the RRMSE (e.g. <10% is excellent, .. etc) for the other error measure?

[image]

- **Reference:** Despotovic, M., Nedic, V., Despotovic, D., & Cvetanovic, S., Evaluation of empirical models for predicting monthly mean horizontal diffuse solar radiation, *Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews*, Volume 56, April 2016, Pages 246-260, ISSN 1364-0321, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.rser.2015.11.058.

Comment: What article is this? Can you provide a complete citation?

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032115013258

Comment: Can RRMSE also to measure model efficiency in forecasting?

Comment: I think Equation (60) is incorrect. One should divide by the average value of measurements, not by the sum.

Answer (score 8):

RMSE is stated in the same units of the original measurement, so if you are comparing distance measuring techniques, you might have an RMSE of 0.29 meters. If you're measuring mountain height or river distances then this is a tiny amount of inaccuracy, perhaps 0.005%. If you're measuring people's height, then you're about 17% off. That percentage variation in accuracy is RRMSE.

RRMSE can also be used to hide inaccuracy. If you're comparing different techniques of measuring large magnitude items, say distances of 10,000 m, one may be established and very accurate, measuring within .05 m accuracy, while the proposed new technique is much less precise, measuring within 200 m accuracy. Those are scary big differences, but when presented as percentages, 2% error sounds pretty good, and the <0.1% error is only slightly better, but in reality it's 4,000x more accurate.