# Is there something like a Root Mean Square Relative Error (RMSRE)? Or: What is the name of this error?

Tags: error, rms

\begin{equation}
\text{RMSRE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}}
\end{equation}
with 
\begin{equation}
 \Delta X_{\text{rel},i} = \frac{X_i}{T_i}-1,
\end{equation}
where $T_i$ is the desired value and $X_i$ is the actual value.

If this error actually exists, then a citable source for it would be greatly appreciated. If it does not exist, then why so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is related to [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413211/is-there-something-like-a-root-mean-square-percentage-error-rmspe-or-what-is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer :** It exists and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032115013258?via%3Dihub) is the reference and also there is a similar [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260615/what-is-the-difference-between-rrmse-and-rmsre/) regarding difference between **R**RMSE & RMS**R**E I would like to draw your attention to. It depends where you apply division to make the error relative!

Mathematically, when you divide the difference between the predicted output and actual(expected) output $T_i-X_i$  by $T_i$ then the error will be considered **Relatively**
which means that each residual is scaled against the actual value or normalized by that.
\begin{equation}
 \Delta X_{\text{rel},i}=\frac{X_i-T_i}{T_i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{RMSRE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{RRMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-T_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_i^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{PRMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-T_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_i^2}}\cdot 100 \%
\end{equation}

Another reference for using RRMSE could be found [here](http://www.waveclimate.com/clams/redesign/help/docs/I113_Validation_BMTA_35-year_Hindcast_17jun2016.pdf) and the last form is known as **r**RMSE as well  as shown [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0005295)

Basically the same approach is used in **MAPE** to express error either **relatively** or in form of **percentage** as the last form. Obviously expression in form of percentage itself includes  relative error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and detailed reply.

Comment: The primary sources for the $\text{RMSRE}$, according to the paper you referenced are [Göçken et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417415006570?via%3Dihub) and [Webber et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378429015300678?via%3Dihub). For completeness and to make [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413211/is-there-something-like-a-root-mean-square-percentage-error-rmspe-or-what-is) a real duplicate, you should add $\text{RMSPE}$.

Comment: [Swanson et al.](https://cssd.ucr.edu/Papers/PDFs/MAPE-R%20EMPIRICAL%20V24%20Swanson%20Tayman%20Bryan.pdf), [Fomby](http://faculty.smu.edu/tfomby/eco5385_eco6380/lecture/Scoring%20Measures%20for%20Prediction%20Problems.pdf) and [Shcherbakov et al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/435e/b6e05fcda264c8c1e7fbcdee7116bb5b1424.pdf)) define the RMSPE as:
\begin{equation}
\text{RMSPE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}} \cdot 100\%
\end{equation}

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't use this. I would argue for the related measure $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg\|\mathbf{\frac{T}{X}}-1\bigg\|$$ for several reasons. That form is more literally proportional modelling error: It allows for direct comparison of different models $\mathbf{T_1}$ and $\mathbf{T_2}$ using $\mathbf{X}$ as the reference values. In that form it is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ times the $1/\mathbf{X}^2$ weighted ordinary-least-squares regression value, and can be parsed into modelling error and noise.

Comment: http://www.waveclimate.com/clams/redesign/help/docs/I113_Validation_BMTA_35-year_Hindcast_17jun2016.pdf has a different formula for RRMSE than the one you cited, @Mario

Comment: @quant_dev, the one stated in P. 13 in your reference is similar, but they used the **A**bsolute value, so I would call it RRM**A**E instead of RRMSE precisely. Geometry-wisely, one estimates error _distance_, and another calculates error based on a _square root area_ within the formula.