# Is there something like a Root Mean Square Percentage Error (RMSPE)? Or: What is the name of this error?

Tags: error, rms

\begin{equation}
\text{RMSPE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta X^2_{\text{rel},i}}\cdot 100\%
\end{equation}
with 
\begin{equation}
 \Delta X_{\text{rel},i}=\frac{X_i}{T_i}-1,
\end{equation}
where $T_i$ is the desired value and $X_i$ is the actual value.

If this error actually exists, then a citable source for it would be greatly appreciated. If it does not exist, then why so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is related to [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413209/is-there-something-like-a-root-mean-square-relative-error-rmsre-or-what-is-t).